# Would wireless router speeds ≫ Internet connection’s speed be distinguishable to a user surfing the web over a home cable modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router

I want to buy a wireless router that is fast enough relative to my Internet connection speed that it won’t be a bottleneck.

Looking at the specs for wireless routers in the market today, I am *thrown off* by the *huge discrepancy* that exist between the capacity (≥ 300 Mbps) of even the rock-bottom budget-priced home-grade wireless routers like [this one](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/?model=TL-WR841N), and the speeds one can get for an internet connection at “home consumer”-level prices, which are typically in the 5-25 Mbps range. Even springing for an [entry-level business-grade account](http://business.comcast.com/internet/business-internet/plans-pricing) will get one only ~50Mbps.

My only explanation for this discrepancy is that the extra capacity of these home-grade routers is there only to speed up the communication between devices *within* the home LAN.

If this guess is correct, then the following would also be true:

> If the speed of the internet connection is < 50Mbps, then a user communicating wirelessly *with the internet* ***will not be able to detect any difference*** between doing so through a 300Mbps router and a 900Mbps router...

(…because the speed of the data transfer would be limited by the (much lower) speed of the internet connection).

Is this deduction correct?

Or, to the contrary, will my web surfing and Netflix streaming indeed be noticeably faster if I shell out for an N900 wireless router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or, to the contrary, will my web surfing and Netflix streaming indeed
>   be noticeably faster if I shell out for an N900 wireless router?

You will 100% never reach the maximum saturation of your router’s capacity based solely on the connection coming from the Internet/WAN. The potential speed of 300Mpbs—for example—is strictly within your home network LAN. Nothing more and nothing less.

And oftentimes vendors market their routers based on raw speed numbers like that instead of protocol being used—802.11b, 802.11g, 802.11n, 802.11ac…—since it’s easier to hype raw speed while ignoring the “ugly” details of protocols and variances in speed.

Meaning, most Mpbs ratings for routers are not false, but rather “thruthy.” Yes, you can *potentially* get up to 300Mpbs via Wi-Fi if your devices all connect to the router at the protocol that supports that specific speed. But if they connect at a protocol that only supports a lower speed, then that is what they get; lower speed.

The reason why many router manufacturers tout their raw Wi-Fi speeds is simple: Currently Wi-Fi connectivity is just not a speed demon compared to a hard-wired Ethernet connection. Meaning if speed is a thing and Wi-Fi is an optional choice—not a sole choice—then always go with wired Ethernet to get 1,000Mpbs (Gigabit Ethernet) speed. So in the Wi-Fi router market, speed bragging rights is a marketing metric since it’s currently nowhere near as fast as a wired Ethernet connection.

Which is all to say is if you are concerned about a router adding a bottleneck to WAN speed, that’s not a concern. But router choice *does* affect speed within the LAN and between different devices on the LAN and this can be a concern if you are—for example—using a PC as a home media server that streams to your portable devices. If your router can’t handle the traffic, your LAN speed will be fairly noticeably bottlenecked and media playback will be noticeably choked.

Comment: There is the standard's ( 802.11n, 802.11ac, etc. ) speed and then there is the actual performance achieved which is limited by the 802.11 hardware itself.  For instance a 802.11ac router released in 2014 will be significantly slower than a 802.11ac router released in 2015 when 2015 802.11ac devices connected to it.  There are some technical reasons ( i.e. the standard was updated ) but 802.11n hardware can also be different dual-band routers for instance will be faster than single-band 802.11n routers

Comment: Indeed.  I admit the 802.11ac comment is time limited it was due to hardware being released for a draft standard then the hardware vendors finding ways to improve their hardware.  Earlier versions of the 802.11 standard have not had that problem even 802.11n draft hardware was compliant with the standard only thing that changed was the number of radios/bands the hardware supported.